# @FeignClient forces @GetMapping with @RequestBody to POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-feign

I have following REST controller with GET method that have BODY, that works fine with tests and postman

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping({"/find"})
    public LocalDateTime findMax(@RequestBody List<ObjectId> ids) {
        //return sth   
    }
}
```

but when FeignClient is used to call service, instead GET request a POST request is generated (@GetMapping annotation is ignored)

```
@FeignClient
public interface CoveragesServiceResource extends CoveragesService {
    @GetMapping({"/find"})
    LocalDateTime findMax(@RequestBody List<ObjectId> ids);
}
```

that gives an error:

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GET request technically can have body but the body should have no meaning as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1602555). You might be able to declare a GET endpoint with a body but some network libraries and tools will simply not support it e.g. Jersey can be configured to allow it but RESTEasy can't [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341305/1602555).

It would be advisable to either declare `/find` as POST or don't use `@RequestBody`.